# Okta Autherization server scopes vs app scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, okta, okta-api

Both Okta applications and authorization servers can define scopes. What is the difference between them? When would you use one for a permission and when the other? Especially when you can send an authorization token as a header which was created with the client id and secret

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is the role of the Authorization Server to issue scopes, which represent the following concepts:

- A high level area of data, such as 'orders'
- The type of operation you can perform on that data, such as 'read'

These can be combined to produce a value such as 'orders_read', and the Authorization Server should also audit which scopes were issued, and which user and application were involved.

Scopes are designed around your back end data, and then you say which (Okta) application is able to use which areas of data via scopes. Most apps would not be given access to high privilege scopes such as 'payroll' or 'payments'.

This [Curity Article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) provides a good overview of scopes and how to design them in order to protect your data.

**WORKED EXAMPLE**

You might add these custom scopes to the Okta system as a whole, representing areas of your company's business data:

- Orders
- Invoicing
- Payments
- Reports
- Shipping

You then configure your Okta applications / clients based on data they need to use, which is usually a subset of the overall scopes defined:

- App 1 might only require Orders and Invoicing
- App 2 might require all of Orders, Payments and Shipping

So when app 1 logs a user in, it will send an authorization redirect with scope values as below. This will result in app 1 being issued access tokens that can only be used against endpoints for these business areas:

- scope = 'orders invoicing'

That is, scopes can provide a mechanism for protecting data by area, when this is needed. For simple apps you might instead choose to start with a single 'default' scope, which allows all apps access to all data.

**OKTA SPECIFICS**

In Okta all clients can access all scopes by default. You can restrict that either by configuring the app itself to only send a request for a subset of scopes, or by setting up a [custom policy](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/configure-access-policy/limit-scopes-clients-can-access/).

Comment: I still didn't read the article, but I still didn't really understand the difference. How does the authorization server audit which application requested the scope? If I define an app in Okta with a scope and then send a token request with that scope to my custom auth sever, it will just check if the scope if defined in the app and won't block it somehow

Comment: I added a section at the end of my answer. In short you are fully in control of scopes and your apps won't be blocked. But you have the option of using different scopes per app if that is ever useful. You might prefer to instead keep scopes simple in the early days, but it is worth being aware of their role.

Comment: You added an example of apps requiring scopes and how they can define their needed scopes. You didn't show how the authorization server comes into play there with its' scopes